# self hosting web pages?

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

we are trying to build a some program that will sit on the clients servers, then a user will enter a url in his browser that will go to our program on his servers. the program will call some data at our servers and will return an image in his browser is it possible to create under wcf self hosing ?

Comment: You mean .. you want a web server ... that can serve images? Is there some reason why the dozen or so that are freely available won't work?

Comment: we need it to be secure , very secure. our servers will get a call from a single program ( our installed web server at the client) returns the image and will display the image at the user browser

Comment: I don't mean to sound trite, but you're _serving images_ ... what security do you require that isn't implemented in a mature, tested and peer reviewed web server?

Comment: Tim thank you for your Patience , but some images like bills need to be secure. our system can get only one secure ID per company and if that company has 200 users we cant give them and dont want to give them ID's so we need it to sit on there servers , call our server by 2 way ssl like we always do with wcf server client architecture and give them the pdf on there web browser. we need it to be custom build with our security system (we have a lot of security).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use a HTTP call to your site at the clients site to get the image or a more sophisticated technology like a web service. There should be no problem if both web servers are connected to the internet.

Comment: it depends what you are experienced with. Your simple problem can be solved by either of the technologies. Here's a good summary on the differences of REST vs SOAP. http://www.oio.de/public/xml/rest-webservices.htm

Comment: To align with your security issues you should definitely use REST or SOAP -- SOAP's extension WS-Encryption provides a high level of security.

Comment: Your backend on the clients side should fetch the image; if not, use REST over a secure connection.

Comment: yes this is what we want. 
can you please direct me to a good article or code example, i thought using REST from the client browser to direct the wcf service on the client server , then the service will do get from our servers return the pdf to the client server then to the client web broswer and show him the pdf.... is it possible ?